# Make environment behaving as a list

Tags: environments, lists

I would like to have

```
\begin{question}
Text
\end{question}
\begin{question}
Text2
\end{question}
```

Behave in the same manner as

```
\begin{enumerate}
\item Text 
\item Text2
\end{enumerate}
```

where Text and Text2 potentially can contain lists also,
so it is required that the 'nested' list is indented properly.
I have tried various solutions, but I either do not manage to get the indentation work,
or fail to have the outer numbering to be on the same line as Text.

Comment: What do you use to "separate" the numbering of two lists then?

Comment: @user202729 I am fine with manually set the numbering style of the inner list. The outer list (question) should be numbered with normal, arabic numbers.

Comment: I'm asking how do you know if the first question environment should be 1 and the second question environment should be 2? If there's some intervening text between the 2 environments should the numbering be reset to 1?

Comment: @user202729 Yes, the numbering of the questions should just be 1,2,3. If there is text in between, it should not affect the numbering.
I think the closest is to just have 'question' to behave as a theorem, as in amsmath, but the indentations are not correct for this solution.

Comment: Have you looked into the ```exam``` package?

Comment: @user202729 for that one can exploit the counter mechanism of LaTeX. Have a look at my answer below. It is possible.

Comment: @Niranjan I'm aware, but in "normal" enumerate environment you can reset the numbering. If OP doesn't need that then yes it's easier.

Comment: @user202729 Ah! I am guessing that won't be the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the `\list` mechanism of LaTeX, you can have something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\newcounter{qno}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{ question }{  }{%
  \refstepcounter{qno}%
  \list{\ignorespaces\theqno.}{}%
  \item
}{\endlist}

\begin{document}
\begin{question}
  What do you think, Kant?
\end{question}

\kant[1-1]
\begin{question}
  What do you think, Kant?
\end{question}

\kant[1-1]
\end{document}
```

Comment: This does exactly what I want, awesome! Can one use refstepcounter inside instead? So that one can add a label after begin{question} and reference its number?

Comment: I figured out how to use refstepcounter, so that one can reference questions. I edited your answer with this update, hope you're ok with that edit.

Comment: Ah! `\refstepcounter` did not come to my mind (despite of me myself having used it several times :P). It is definitely a great suggestion, so I am okay with it being added, but you removed a dependency and the document-class from my originally posted code making it uncompilable, so I will just add that back again.

Comment: Is there a reason to catch the body of the environment `{question}` (with the specifier `b`)? You could avoid that argument (and put `\ignorespaces` in the second part of the environment). With that programmation, verbatim material would be allowed in your environment.

Comment: @F.Pantigny This makes sense! I will edit it. Thanks a lot :)